# How to add a scroll bar aside a widget without overlaying in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, scrollview, scrollbar

I am trying to add a scroll bar to a GridView in Flutter using ScrollBar widget. I want the scroll bar to be always visible. However, the scroll bar overlays (comes in front) of the grid. Is there a way to put the scroll bar to the side without overlaying?

```
Scaffold(
  body: Scrollbar(
    thumbVisibility: true,
    interactive: true,
    child: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 5,
      crossAxisSpacing: 6,
      children: List.generate(
        100,
        (index) => Text('I am text$index'),
       ),
     ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add padding to `GridView` to move `Scrollbar` aside. Like below:

```
   GridView.count(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      crossAxisCount: 5,
      crossAxisSpacing: 6,
      children: List.generate(
        100,
        (index) => Text('I am text$index'),
      ),
    ),
```

Hope it helps.